# Phantom type makes pattern matching irrefutable, but that seemingly does not work inside do notation

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt

Please look at the code.  I believe using phantom type makes the pattern matching irrefutable so there is no need in `MonadFail` instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wincomplete-uni-patterns #-}

data Type = I | S

data T t where
    TI :: Int -> T 'I
    TS :: String -> T 'S

ti :: T 'I
ti = TI 42

test :: Monad m => m Int 
test = do
    (TI v) <- return ti
    return v
```

But I am getting this error:

```
    • Could not deduce (MonadFail m)
        arising from a do statement
        with the failable pattern ‘(TI v)’
```

What's wrong with this approach?

I checked this with ghc 9.0.2 and  8.10.4.

By the way, matching it in `let` does not produce any warning even in the presence of `-Wincomplete-uni-patterns` option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach; it should work as you expect it to. It's a known bug in GHC that it currently doesn't: [Take exhaustiveness checking into consideration when using MonadFailDesugaring (#15681) (comment)](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/15681#note_165436)

Until they fix it, you can work around it by writing `~(TI v) <- return ti` instead of `(TI v) <- return ti`.